# Ubuntu 22.04 Bluetooth won't turn on

Tags: bluetooth, dell, 22.04

I have a Dell T3500 with Ubuntu 22.04 where my Bluetooth won't turn on. I have looked up other questions on this subject but none have quite the same problem I do, namely this error:

```
"Apr 28 20:45:26 ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500 bluetoothd[1639]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.85 tried to register 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb which is already regist>
Apr 28 20:45:26 ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500 bluetoothd[1639]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.85 tried to register 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb which is already regist>"
```

Here's the output of some terminal queries. The daemon seems to be running and the dongle is recognized.

```
ned@ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500:~$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
 bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-04-28 15:41:16 CDT; 7h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1639 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 14211)
     Memory: 2.0M
        CPU: 142ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1639 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 28 15:41:16 ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Apr 28 15:41:16 ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500 bluetoothd[1639]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Apr 28 15:41:16 ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 28 15:41:16 ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500 bluetoothd[1639]: Starting SDP server
Apr 28 15:41:16 ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500 bluetoothd[1639]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
Apr 28 20:45:26 ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500 bluetoothd[1639]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.85 tried to register 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb which is already regist>
Apr 28 20:45:26 ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500 bluetoothd[1639]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.85 tried to register 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb which is already regist>


ned@ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500:~$ sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
[sudo] password for ned: 
[    5.343606] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.343626] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.343628] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.343631] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.343633] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.343637] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.408195] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[    8.206756] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.206760] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.206764] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.886814] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[   14.886821] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Failed to suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[ 9693.300538] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[ 9693.300544] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Failed to suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[10822.275734] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...

ned@ned-Precision-WorkStation-T3500:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1681] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1028:0293]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
3f:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c70] (rev 02)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C170
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 413c:2112 Dell Computer Corp. Dell USB Wired Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: The easiest way is to buy another USB dongle.

Comment: I have the same issue. I updated my laptop to Ubuntu 22.04 and now the config menu says that:"no Bluetooth adapter found". I use a Dell Inspiron 3000 Why I have to buy an USb Dongle if I have an on-board bluetooth?

Comment: Pilot6: The dongle works fine when I boot into Windows on the same computer so I don't think that'll help, although I'll try it anyway.